# Pass variable throw closure

Tags: rust, telegram-bot

I have some async method of structure:

```
impl ImageBot {
    pub async fn run(&self) {

        let bot_name = self.bot_name.clone();
        let token = self.token.clone();
        let http_host = self.http_host.clone();
        let web_hook_url = self.web_hook_url.clone();

        let bot = teloxide::Bot::new(token).auto_send();

        teloxide::repls2::repl_with_listener(
            bot.clone(),
            |message: Message, bot: AutoSend<teloxide::Bot>| async move {
                let name = bot_name;

                let command_with_args = parse_command(message.text().unwrap(), name);

                if let Some((command, args)) = command_with_args {
                    command_handler(bot, message.clone(), command, args).await
                } else {
                    //
                }

                respond(())
            },
            webhook(bot.clone(), http_host, web_hook_url).await,
        )
        .await;
    }
}
```

I need to get `bot_name` for [parse_command](https://github.com/teloxide/teloxide/blob/038b5a1ae25703c6119cc175959ceaa570fc5e18/src/utils/command.rs#L298):

```
|message: Message, bot: AutoSend<teloxide::Bot>| async move {
                let name = bot_name;

                let command_with_args = parse_command(message.text().unwrap(), name);
```

Now I get error:

`Expected a closure that implements the Fn trait, but this closure only implements FnOnce`

on this:

`|message: Message, bot: AutoSend<teloxide::Bot>| async move`

How can I do this?

Comment: What's not working with your current implementation?

Comment: I get error: 
`Expected a closure that implements the Fn trait, but this closure only implements FnOnce`
 on that: 
`|message: Message, bot: AutoSend<teloxide::Bot>| async move`

Comment: Your closure consumes the captured variable `bot_name` when run, which renders it `FnOnce`. You can only consume a captured value once. You may need to clone `bot_name` whenever the closure runs.

Comment: I try this: ` let name = bot_name.clone();`. But error is not gone. How can I clone it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're hitting is a common one currently due to the lack of async closures, and hence reliance on `async move` blocks, reformatting a bit:

```rust
|message: Message, bot: AutoSend<teloxide::Bot>| {
    async move {
        let name = bot_name;
        [...]
```

this means `bot_name` will be moved into the closure, then on the first call *it will be moved into the block* from the closure.

This means the first call *consumes* `bot_name`, and in order to do so has to consume the closure itself, therefore the function can't be called repeatedly.

The solution then is to create a copy *inside the closure*, which you can then move into the block:

```rust
move |message: Message, bot: AutoSend<teloxide::Bot>| {
    let name = bot_name.clone();
    async move {
        [...]
```

- the closure is `move`, this moves `bot_name` into the closure  because since `Clone::clone` takes a reference otherwise rust will only try to capture a reference, which is unlikely to work out
- then we create a local `name` copy, which can be moved inside the block, and the closure doesn't care that it gets dropped during the async process because it still has its `bot_name`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `teloxide::repls2::repl_with_listener` expects to get a closure, that can be called multiple times, however, the closure you're passing is consuming the `name` variable when it's called.

This line is the problem:

```rust
let command_with_args = parse_command(message.text().unwrap(), name);
```

You should rewrite it like so:

```rust
let command_with_args = parse_command(message.text().unwrap(), &name);
```

So that `name` is only borrowed every time the closure is invoked, instead of beeing consumed